# angular2 rc5 and routing Cannot match any routes:

Tags: angular

I am trying to use rc5 with routes.

Here is what I want to do.

1. Go to login page
2. when logged in go to dashboard route with a nav on the top.
3. A user clicks a link in the nav and the content is shown in an aux router.

Here is my app.routes.ts

```
const routeConfig: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'models',component: ModelsComponent, outlet:'content'}
];

// - Updated Export
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routeConfig);
```

Here is the html for the dashboard:

```
<div>
  <div class="dashhead">
    <div class="dashhead-titles">
      <h6 class="dashhead-subtitle">Qauntitative Treasury Analytics</h6>
      <h3 class="dashhead-title">QTA Model Builder</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="dashhead-toolbar">

      <span class="dashhead-toolbar-divider hidden-xs"></span>

    </div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav nav-bordered">

    <li [class.active]="isCurrentRoute(['models'])"><a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['models']">Models</a></li>

    <li><a (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
```

Here is my error when I click the models link in the nav:

```
core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'dashboard/models'
```

Comment: Your route config doesn't contain a `home` route.

Comment: I removed the commet html - home was in a comment

Comment: [routerLink]="['/models']" did not work

Comment: Does it work if you use the default outlet, without `outlet: 'content'`?

Comment: no it does not work

Comment: I guess this requires a Plunker t reproduce. I don't see how this could be diagnosed without.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
routerLink='/home'
```

instead of :

```
[routerLink]="['home']"
```

Comment: `[routerLink]="['/home']"` should do the same (your's is more succinct though)